# How do I enumerate and use OpenGL on a headless GPU?

Tags: linux, opengl, x11

Despite days of research, I can't seem to find a reliable way to programmatically create GL[ES] contexts on secondary GPUs.  On my laptop, for example, I have the Intel GPU driving the panel, and a secondary NVIDIA card not connected to anything.  `optirun` and `primusrun` let me run on the NVIDIA card, but then I can't detect the Intel GPU. I also don't want to require changing xorg.conf to add a dummy display.

I have tried a number of extensions, but none seem to work correctly:

- `glXEnumerateVideoDevicesNV` returns 0 devices.
- `eglQueryDevicesEXT` returns 0 devices.
- `eglGetPlatformDisplay` only works with the main panel and gives me an Intel context

I am fine getting my hands dirty, e.g. rolling my own loader, but I can't seem to find any documentation for where to start.  I've looked at the source for `optirun` but it just seems to do redirection. Obviously something equivalent to Windows' `IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters` would be ideal, but I'm fine with anything that works without additional system configuration.